# Different treatment of NaN in sort for Series and DataFrame

Tags: pandas

NaNs are treated differently when I use a Series than when I use a DataFrame of the same data containing NaN values and do a sort in *descending* order. In the Series they are put at the end (which is what I want), in the DataFrame they are put at the front, which is not what I want. Any reason for the difference in behavior? Any way to put the NaNs at the end when sorting a DataFrame in descending order?

```
a = Series(data = array([1,5,3,7,nan,10]))
a.sort(ascending=False)
print a  # Gives correct result with NaNs at end

b = DataFrame(array([1,5,3,7,nan,10]))
b.sort(columns=0,ascending=False)  # Gives wrong result with NaNs at beginning
```

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using, this works as expected, in fact the sort order for a dataframe is the same as it was created. Do `print pd.version.version` to get the version

Comment: Actually this works correctly, ignore my last comment, `NaN` either appears at the beginning for `ascending=False` or at the end for `ascending=True`

Comment: in 0.14 their is a ``na_position`` argument to control this